# Can I use a 3-pin to 4-pin extension and be able to control the speed?

Tags: fan, computer-building

I have a case fans thats 3-pin if i add a PWM 4-pin extension cable to the 3-pin fans so that I can plug the 4-pin into my motherboard. Would I be able to control the RPM/Speed of the fans if I do it this way? Sorry if its confusing

Comment: What adapter are you referring to? 3 pin fans do not work the same as 4 pin fans. A simple “extension cable” would not change that. If it changes the connection from 3 pin to 4 pin it is not just an extension cable. Most motherboards have fan headers for both 3 pin and 4 pin fans. Some motherboards have configuration in the BIOS to tell the motherboard if it should treat the fan as 3 pin or 4 pin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Three-wire and four-wire CPU fans, what's the difference?](https://superuser.com/questions/1126136/three-wire-and-four-wire-cpu-fans-whats-the-difference)

Answer (score 1):

From here https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/is-there-a-way-to-control-3-pin-fans.2905718/

> For 3-pin fans, the connections to it are Ground to Pin #1, +VDC
>   (varying) to Pin #2, and Speed signal on Pin #3. To control fan speed,
>   the mobo header must alter the voltage on Pin #2, ranging form +12 VDC
>   (max) to about +5 VDC. (At voltage less than 5 VDC, the fan may stall
>   and not re-start until the voltage is increased.) This method is
>   called "Voltage Control Mode" or sometimes "DC Mode". The fan speed
>   signal is a series of pulses (2 per revolution) generated inside the
>   motor and sent back on Pin #3 to the mobo for counting and display.
>   Interestingly, this signal is NOT used for actual control of the
>   speed.
>
> 4-pin fans work differently. They still use almost the same signals on
>   those first 3 pins, but with one important difference. Pin #2 always
>   has +12 VDC on it, never reduced. Then the new Pin #4 has the PWM
>   signal. Inside the fan a small chip uses that PWM signal to control
>   the flow of current through the motor from the +12 VDC supply, thus
>   manipulating speed. This method is called "PWM Mode".

So the answer is that an adapter would not work because the method of control and signals employed are fundamentally different.